# How to open new window in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

How to open new window in angular6

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(objectUrl, filename);
    let opner = window.open(objectUrl,`enter code here` '_blank', 'height=700,width=700');
}
```

How to open in new window in angular 6 . its working fine in Chrome but not Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

window.open("http://google.com",'text example', 'height=700,width=700');

Answer (score 0):

IE will fail if there are spaces or "-" in the second parameter. So, remove the spaces and try this:

```
window.open(objectUrl, 'enter_code_here', 'height=700, width=700');
```